# How to see if a string or a subset of the same exists in other list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples, subset

I'm trying to check if a string inside a tuple in a list is found in another list or if a subset of this string also exists.

Example: I have this 3 lists.

```py
[('g1', 'C1C2C8C9'), ('g2', 'C5C6'), ('g3', 'C3C4'), ('g5', 'C1C3C7'), ('g1g5', 'C1'), ('g3g5', 'C3'), ('g4g5', 'C7')]
[('g1', 'C3C4C5C7'), ('g3', 'C1C2C6C8C9'), ('g4', 'C1C2C3C4C6'), ('g3g4', 'C1'), ('g3g4', 'C2'), ('g1g4', 'C3'), ('g1g4', 'C4'), ('g3g4', 'C6'), ('g2g3', 'C8'), ('g3g5', 'C9')]
[('g1', 'C1C2C3C4C5C7C8C9'), ('g2', 'C1C2C5C6C7C8'), ('g3', 'C1C2C5C7'), ('g4', 'C1C2C5C6C7'), ('g5', 'C1C2C5C7C9'), ('g1g4g3g2g5', 'C1'), ('g5g2g4g3g1', 'C2'), ('g5g2g4g1g3', 'C5'), ('g4g2', 'C6'), ('g5g2g4g3g1', 'C7'), ('g2g1', 'C8'), ('g1g5', 'C9')]
```

I want to check if `('g1', 'C1C2C8C9')` exists in another list (is present in the third one) but I also want to check if `('g1', 'C1C2')` exists in another list, `('g1', 'C1C8')`, `('g1', 'C1C9')`, `('g1', 'C1C2C8')`, `('g1', 'C1C8C9')`, and so one and do it for every tuple in the list.

I now was trying to separate all the C repeating the g in different tuples and the idea was to try to get and join all the possibilities and compare, but I don't think this is a good solution:
run_all(matrix_3) is the 3 lists.

```
import textwrap as tw
lfd = []
for lists in run_all(matrix_3):
    #print(lists)
    l = []
    for tup in lists:
        if len(tup[1])>2:
            lt1=tw.wrap(tup[1],2)
            for c1 in lt1:
                tupl1=(tup[0],c1)
                l.append(tupl1)
        elif len(tup[1])<=2 and len(tup[0])>2:
            lt0=tw.wrap(tup[0],2)
            for c0 in lt0:
                tupl0=(c0,tup[1])
                l.append(tupl0)
    lfd.append(l)
print(lfd)
```

Comment: The easy way to do this kind of searching is to build a dictionary where your values are keys.  Then Python does the search for you.

Comment: But still, how can I compare substrings of the original strings in the tuples?

Comment: What is `tw.wrap()`?

Comment: `if any(tup1[1] in tup2[1] for tup2 in list_of_tuples)` will tell you if `tup1[1]` is a substring of any of the strings in `list_of_tuples`

Comment: Sorry, forgot to put the import in the code, I've already change it.

Answer (score 0):

I may have way overcomplicated things... but I think the problem you're describing is actually way more complicated than it appears at first glance.

```
from itertools import product, chain, combinations
from pprint import pprint

def run_all():
    # Returns Testing Data
    return ([('g1', 'C1C2C8C9'), ('g2', 'C5C6'), ('g3', 'C3C4'), ('g5', 'C1C3C7'), ('g1g5', 'C1'), ('g3g5', 'C3'), ('g4g5', 'C7')],
            [('g1', 'C3C4C5C7'), ('g3', 'C1C2C6C8C9'), ('g4', 'C1C2C3C4C6'), ('g3g4', 'C1'), ('g3g4', 'C2'), ('g1g4', 'C3'), ('g1g4', 'C4'), ('g3g4', 'C6'), ('g2g3', 'C8'), ('g3g5', 'C9')],
            [('g1', 'C1C2C3C4C5C7C8C9'), ('g2', 'C1C2C5C6C7C8'), ('g3', 'C1C2C5C7'), ('g4', 'C1C2C5C6C7'), ('g5', 'C1C2C5C7C9'), ('g1g4g3g2g5', 'C1'), ('g5g2g4g3g1', 'C2'), ('g5g2g4g1g3', 'C5'), ('g4g2', 'C6'), ('g5g2g4g3g1', 'C7'), ('g2g1', 'C8'), ('g1g5', 'C9')])

def remove_letters(x,y):
    # Used to remove letters from inner tuples
    return x.replace('g', ''), y.replace('C', '')

def combos(x):
    # Returns every length combination of a string
    return (com for sub in range(len(x)) for com in combinations(x, sub+1))

def inner_chain(l):
    # Returns the product of every combination of each tuple
    return (product(combos(x), combos(y)) for x, y in l)

def return_letters(x, y):
    # Used to add the letters back 
    return 'g'+'g'.join(x), 'C'+'C'.join(y)

# Do your own, this is just for testing
data = run_all()

# Removes all the letters to make things more simple
data = ((remove_letters(x, y) for x, y in t) for t in data)

# For every list in the lists, returns a set of all possible variations
data = list(set(chain.from_iterable(inner_chain(l))) for l in data)

# Scans through the data, one set at a time and adds values
# from the given set that exist in any other set of the data
lfd = set()
for i, l in enumerate(data):
    others = set(chain.from_iterable(data[:i] + data[i+1:]))
    lfd.update(l & others)

# Puts the letters back and formats again as a list of tuples.
exists_in_others = [return_letters(x, y) for x, y in lfd]

pprint(sorted(exists_in_others), compact=True)
```

Output:

```
[('g1', 'C1'), ('g1', 'C1C2'), ('g1', 'C1C2C8'), ('g1', 'C1C2C8C9'),
 ('g1', 'C1C2C9'), ('g1', 'C1C8'), ('g1', 'C1C8C9'), ('g1', 'C1C9'),
 ('g1', 'C2'), ('g1', 'C2C8'), ('g1', 'C2C8C9'), ('g1', 'C2C9'), ('g1', 'C3'),
 ('g1', 'C3C4'), ('g1', 'C3C4C5'), ('g1', 'C3C4C5C7'), ('g1', 'C3C4C7'),
 ('g1', 'C3C5'), ('g1', 'C3C5C7'), ('g1', 'C3C7'), ('g1', 'C4'), ('g1', 'C4C5'),
 ('g1', 'C4C5C7'), ('g1', 'C4C7'), ('g1', 'C5'), ('g1', 'C5C7'), ('g1', 'C7'),
 ('g1', 'C8'), ('g1', 'C8C9'), ('g1', 'C9'), ('g1g5', 'C1'), ('g2', 'C5'),
 ('g2', 'C5C6'), ('g2', 'C6'), ('g2', 'C8'), ('g3', 'C1'), ('g3', 'C1C2'),
 ('g3', 'C2'), ('g4', 'C1'), ('g4', 'C1C2'), ('g4', 'C1C2C6'), ('g4', 'C1C6'),
 ('g4', 'C2'), ('g4', 'C2C6'), ('g4', 'C6'), ('g4', 'C7'), ('g5', 'C1'),
 ('g5', 'C1C7'), ('g5', 'C7'), ('g5', 'C9')]
```

- Note, this assumes that `C1C2` == `C2C1`

Comment: Thanks for your answer BeRT2me!
Is it possible to keep like the index of the list where the substring appears, and get an output with something like a dictionary where I have the tuple as key and a value with the numbers of the index corresponding to the lists that they appear. 
Example:
`('g1', 'C1C2C8')` appears in the first list and in the third, so the output will be something like `{ ('g1', 'C1C2C8') : [0,2] , ...... }`
doesn't necessary needs to be a dictionary but it was what came to my mind

Comment: That certainly should be possible. If you modify the loop `for i, l in enumerate(data):` to look at other cells one by one, instead of all together, then you can populate a dictionary of matches. Good Luck!